# Implementing React Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a `Dropdown` menu using React.
But I've no idea how to implement `handleClose()`.

[image]

I want:

1. Clicking the body / anything outside the `<Dropdown>` => `handleClose()`
2. Clicking any `<ActionMenu>` => `handleClose()`
3. Clicking any children inside the `<ActionMenu>` => `handleClose()` **if `preventDefault()` was not called**
4. Clicking any `<ActionMenu enabled={false}>` => do nothing
5. Clicking any children inside the `<ActionMenu enabled={false}>` => do nothing
6. Clicking any disabled children inside the `<ActionMenu>` => do nothing
7. Clicking any `<NonActionMenu>` => do nothing
8. Clicking any children inside the `<NonActionMenu>` => do nothing
9. `<Dropdown>` lost focus (`onBlur=`) because an element **outside** dropdown got focus => `handleClose()`
10. `<Dropdown>` lost focus (`onBlur=`) because an element **inside** dropdown got focus => do nothing

Implementing `<Dropdown onBlur={() => handleClose()} ...>` works for point 9 but failed for point 10.

Can you suggest your idea?

I've no sandbox because the project is quite complex.
But you can fork & modify here: [my project](https://github.com/heyymarco/nodestrap-hooks)

Comment: The `handleClose()` should just render the drop-down list. Nothing more. Any logic to Call the function should be done outside that. For point 10, an onFocus attribute calling the handleClose should be passed to each drop-down item.

Comment: Inside the `handleClose()` is calling `props.?onClose()`, so the user can decide to update/refuse the state: `onClose={() => setShow(false)}`. I'm stuggling where to spread the event for triggering `handleClose()`

Comment: `onFocus` should not causing `handleClose()`. Imagine a user click on an item and suddenly cancel the click (by dragging out -or- holding left click followed by right click -or- by tab key). The item got focus but not clicked.

Comment: My bad, I didn't mean onFocus. I meant onClick or when the Enter key is pressed. So when an item is clicked. It is chosen first of all and then sets the show to false which is what the handleClose function does

Comment: ok, it works, thanks. I forgot to implement enter key.

Comment: how about clicking/focusing the page/another control/browser lost focus? The native dropdown & contextMenu having that behavior.

Comment: You mean clicking outside the dropdown to close it?

Comment: yes, including focus to any element outside the dropdown also closing it.

Comment: I made an answer to the question. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the click, you can add an event listener to the window object to take care of any click outside the dropdown wrapper. You can also modify this for the enter key:

```
   window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        const dropDownWrapper = document.querySelector('#id of dropdown wrapper');
        const path = e.path || (e.composedPath && e.composedPath());
        if (!path.some(x => !(x instanceof SVGElement) && x.id && x.id === '#id of dropdown wrapper')) {
          dropDownWrapper.querySelector('.class of dropdownlist') ?
            x.querySelector('.class of dropdownlist').style.display = 'none' : null
          } else{
            dropDownWrapper.querySelector('.class of dropdownlist') ?
            x.querySelector('.class of dropdownlist').style.display = 'block' : null
          }
   }, true);
```

Comment: hmm interesting. so it basically filter out any element === dropdownWrapper || childOrDescendantOf(element, dropdownWrapper), right?

Comment: yes, exactly. Also takes care of the element being an svg. They tend to throw an error onClick if not taken care of

Comment: I prefer `focus` instead of `click`, but `focus` is not bubbling in vanilla dom, only in React's synthetic event. How about handling `tab` key?

Comment: I'm not sure about this. But I think you should be able to replace the click with focus

Comment: unfortunately `focus` is not bubbling from child to parent to window. Attaching `addEventListener` to every element is impractical & poor performance. Maybe handling tab key + click is better.

Comment: Hmm...you are right!
I currently don't know of any other way though. I'm sorry

Comment: after I debugging Bootstrap's dropdown code, it listen `click` & `keyup` TAB on document object & using `composePath()` to inspect the target element. Your algorithm is pretty close to it. Why you choose `window` instead of `document`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237275/discussion-between-uchechukwu-nwafor-and-heyyy-marco).